# Finding equal matrix lines

Tags: r, matrix, row, point, equality

I have a matrix in which each row represents a data point (it's a nxp matrix with n p-dimensional points), and I need to find if there is a pair of equal points.

With only two points, I could just apply `dist`, but as the amount of points increase, so does the amount of comparisons I need to do with `dist` (as I'm comparing only two points at a time).

So, as I'm starting to use big matrices, I need a quick way to find if any two points are equal (or if there are two equal rows in this matrix).

Any suggestions?

Edit: as I don't need to return the numbers of the equal rows (I just need to verify if any two are equal), I guess I could create a matrix with no duplicated lines and just compare the number of lines between this matrix and the original matrix. What do you think?

Comment: Look at the `duplicated` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `unique` function,  which is specifically set up to allow you to check for either unique rows or columns in a matrix.  Or, depending on whether you want to save the reduced matrix or not,  you could use `duplicated` as juba pointed out.

Comment: thanks! I just need to use `nrow(x)!=nrow(unique(x))`, and it'll return true if there is a duplicated row!

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is large, consider using data tables.

```
library(data.table)
n  <- 1e6
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x.1=round(runif(n,0,100)),
                x.2=round(runif(n,0,100)),
                x.3=round(runif(n,0,100)),
                x.4=round(runif(n,0,100)))
dt <- data.table(df)

system.time(df.dupe <- duplicated(df))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  16.55    0.01   16.60 
system.time(dt.dupe <- duplicated(dt))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   9.79    0.05    9.83 
setkeyv(dt,colnames(dt))
system.time(dt.dupe <- duplicated(dt))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.08    0.00    0.07
```

So without keys, data tables are about 40% faster. WIth keys they are about 160X faster. Of course you have to create the keys (sort), which takes about 10 sec so if you're only doing this once, better to use the unkeyed data table.